# Selecting Dynamically Created Radio Button Group in Javascript and getting inner text to show

Tags: javascript, dynamic, radio-button

I dynamically created radio buttons as part of a function using the following code:

```
for(var j=0; j<currentQuestion.choices.length; j++){
    var choiceText = currentQuestion.choices[j];
    var newRadioButton = document.createElement("input");
    newRadioButton.name="optionsList";
    newRadioButton.type="radio";
    newRadioButton.value = choiceText;

    newRadioButton.innerHTML = choiceText;
    label.appendChild(newRadioButton);
}
```

The radio buttons are successfully created, but there are still 2 problems:

**1) The innerHTML of each radio button is NOT showing up in the browser, although it shows up when I console log each radio button. So in the browser I'm seeing a radio button with no text next to it, but the console shows that I have text between the input tags**

**2) I cannot figure out how to reference the dynamically created radio buttons to later on check which one has been selected.**

I've tried

```
var radioButtonsGroup = document.label1.optionsList;
```

or

```
var radioButtonsGroup = document.getElementsByName("optionsList");
```

or

```
var radioButtonsGroup = document.getElementsByTagName("inputs");
```

but they all return undefined.

Comment: A radio button is an input, an input is a self closing element, it has no content nor any innerHTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Input elements do not support inner text/html. You should add a label for each of the radio buttons and associate it with it. Code below:

```
for(var j=0; j<currentQuestion.choices.length; j++){
    var choiceText = currentQuestion.choices[j];
    var id = "radio-id-" + j;
    var p = document.createElement("p");

    var newRadioButton = document.createElement("input");
    var text = document.createElement("label");
    newRadioButton.name="optionsList";
    newRadioButton.type="radio";
    text.innerHTML = choiceText;
    text.htmlFor = id;

    p.appendChild(newRadioButton);
    p.appendChild(text);

    label.appendChild(p);
}
```